# JavaScript - Populate value of elements on different forms based on change

Tags: javascript, forms

I have three forms on one page.

I need to change the value of specific form elements (on separate forms) when another form element changes.

Here is the basic function I'm trying to get to work.  I believe my issue is in addressing the other elements requiring the change.

```
function myFunction(inp) {
  if(inp.id == "position") {
    document.getElementById("frmStripePayment").elements["position1"].value = inp.value;
    document.getElementById("frmNoPayment").elements["position2"].value = inp.value;
  }
}
```

The data I need comes from a basic select box with an onchange function.

```html
<select name="position" id="position" style="WIDTH: 150px" onchange="myFunction(this)" >
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score -2):

Your function myFunction aims to change the value of specific form elements on separate forms when the value of the position select box changes. However, it seems that the code you provided is not addressing the elements correctly.

To address this issue, you can use the querySelector method to select the specific form elements by their IDs. Here's an updated version of your function:

```
function myFunction(inp) {
  if (inp.id == "position") {
    document.querySelector("#frmStripePayment input[name='position1']").value = inp.value;
    document.querySelector("#frmNoPayment input[name='position2']").value = inp.value;
  }
}
```

In this updated code, querySelector is used to select the form elements based on their IDs and names. The syntax #frmStripePayment input[name='position1'] selects an input element with the name position1 inside the form with the ID frmStripePayment. Similarly, #frmNoPayment input[name='position2'] selects an input element with the name position2 inside the form with the ID frmNoPayment.

Make sure the form IDs and input names are correct and match your HTML structure.

With this updated code, when the position select box value changes, the corresponding form elements on both forms (frmStripePayment and frmNoPayment) will be updated with the new value.

***Note:*** If the position1 and position2 form elements are not input elements, you may need to adjust the selector accordingly based on the type of elements you're targeting (e.g., , , etc.).

*I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any further questions.*

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Comment: _"However, it seems that the code you provided is not addressing the elements correctly."_ - and why would you be saying that? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements is still implemented in all browsers.